# Is there a way to have plain text/string as an activity output in Azure Data Factory

Tags: email, if-statement, azure-data-factory

I have a set of if Conditions where if they are true, they send out an email, I have set an alert that if all conditions are false, it will send out an email saying this.

I have a Fail activity for false in each of the if conditions, so I can set an output, however even when an email is sent, it says the pipeline fails. The issue here is that if the pipeline fails, it sends out an email saying it failed. Is there a way to format the false output so that it shows a success rather than a fail whilst also having in mind that I need an output for each condition so if they all are false, it sends out an email saying no condition is met?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a pipeline **variable** and use the `Set Variable` activity inside the **false case** to add your plain text or description to that variable. You can use this variable in later activities.

You can use the `Switch` activity for validating multiple conditions and use other activities for each case.

Refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-switch-activity) for more information.